# jQuery: How to create element then wrap this around another existing element?

Tags: jquery, wrapper, element, word-wrap, creation

So I know how to use `.wrap`, `.wrapInner` and `.wrapAll` but I am wondering how to use the quick creation syntax introduced in jQuery 1.4 and the wrap function together.

Basically I want to be able to use

```
var targetUl = $(this), // would be populated by script
    maxWidth = 1400;    // would be populated by script

$('<div />', {
    'id':'wrap',
    'css': {
        'width': maxWidth,
        'overflow':'hidden'
    }
}).wrapAround(targetUl);
```

Kinda like the `.appendTo` method works but for wrapping stuff…

Can this be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
targetUl.wrap(
    $('<div />', {
        'id':'wrap',
        'css': {
            'width': maxWidth,
            'overflow':'hidden'
        }
    })
);
```

Comment: nice, didn't realize I could simply drop that 'creator syntax' into the `.wrap` function.

Comment: Since wrap *clones* the element, this will unnecessarily create two elements: http://jsfiddle.net/qBkA5/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) is what you're looking for. It provides this functionality in a neater way