# Wrap one element with another, retaining reference to wrapper?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The jQuery `wrap()` method does not wrap using element you created, but a duplicate:

```
var $orig = $('p'); // some existing element
var $wrap = $('<div>').css({border:'1px solid red'});
$orig.wrap($wrap);
$wrap.append('<p>SMOKE YOU</p>'); // does not appear after the original element
```

If you are not convinced, you can see a live version of the above here: http://jsfiddle.net/QRmY6/

How do I best create non-trivial dynamic content to wrap around an existing node *while retaining a reference to the wrapper that ends up around the content*?

Comment: This related question does not answer the need to retain the reference to the wrapper: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190946/jquery-how-to-create-element-then-wrap-this-around-another-existing-element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best alternatives I have come up with are:

```
// Technique 1 - swap it out and then embed it via append
var $wrap = $('<div>').css({border:'1px solid red'});
$orig.replaceWith($wrap);
$wrap.append($orig);

// Technique 2 - create it inline and then modify it
var $wrap = $orig.wrap('<div>').parent().css({border:'1px solid red'});
```

Comment: All those `$` want to make me puke. It's not PHP.

Comment: @ThiefMaster My apologies to your gastrointestinal state. :) Some of us choose to prefix variables with `$` as a mini-Hungarian-notation hint that the variable holds a jQuery object and not a DOM object.

Answer (score 1):

Although this has been asked a long time ago, it is still an issue (as of june 2015) in jQuery (v1.11.1). Here's my workaround, which feels a bit.. well, shall we say 'special', but works nonetheless:

```
var $orig = $('p'); // some existing element
var $wrap = $('<div>').css({border:'1px solid red'});

$wrap = $orig.wrap($wrap).parent(); //the object that is being wrapped is returned, so selecting its parent will get the wrapper. Re-setting that in the $wrap variable will retain the wrapper for reference

$wrap.append('<p>SMOKE YOU</p>'); // this will now work
```

Note: the caveat is that the `$wrap` element is no longer re-usable for wrapping, as it now contains the `$orig` element. Workaround for that is by using `add()` in another 'special' way:

```
var $orig = $('p'); // some existing element
var $wrap = $('<div id="wrapper">').css({border:'1px solid red'});

$wrap = $wrap.add($orig.wrap($wrap.clone().empty()).parent()); //the object that is being wrapped is returned, so calling for its parent will return the wrapper.

$wrap.append('<p>SMOKE YOU</p>'); // this will now work

$wrap = $wrap.add( $('div.otherdiv').wrap($wrap.clone().empty()).parent())

console.log($wrap); //as you can see the $wrap variable now contains two divs

$wrap.css({'border' : '1px solid blue'}); //this will now work on all wraps
```

It's not very clear code, but it works! See [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c_kick/d71emqz5/) for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Surprised that jQuery isn't smart enough to keep the reference. Here is an easy vanilla JS way:

```
orig.parentNode.replaceChild(wrapper,orig);
wrapper.appendChild(orig);
```